# Calling Methods in JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I got a class in JavaScript. In this class, I have a method checking the input of the text fields. When the body of the html document is loading, I want to call this method for a first time. After that, I want to use the "onchange()" event.

```
//##############
//# Javascript #
//##############

class NoteController{
  constructor() {
    this.store = new NoteStore(); // instance of a dataStore
  }

  HandleInputFields(){ // Enable / Disable a button by validation
    var input = document.getElementById('edtNoteTitle').value; // Get the input text from the field
    var inputIsValid = true;

    if(input.length < 1) // text is empty
        inputIsValid = false;
    else if (this.store.notes.some(n => n.title === input)) // check for duplicates in the store
        inputIsValid = false;

    document.getElementById('btnCreateNote').disabled = !inputIsValid; // disable the button or keep it enabled
  }
}

//########
//# HTML #
//########

<body onload="HandleInputFields()"> // Disable the button when loading the Document

<input type="text" id="edtNoteTitle" onchange="HandleInputFields()"> // Validate the Input field

</body>
```

So when I open up my document, it says, "HandleInputFields()" is not defined. How can I call this method correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the method as a `static` one and access it via its `class`' scope.

So in `class NoteController { ...`

change `HandleInputFields() {` to `static HandleInputFields() {`
 and then access it via

```
<body onload="NoteController.HandleInputFields()">
```

---

Explanation: currently you're trying to access method without context which fallbacks to `window.HandleInputFields()`. Your intent is however to access it via `NoteController`'s context, thus the call `NoteController.HandleInputFields()`. However, to be able to make the call directly on a class and not on an instance, you need to define it as [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).

Comment: Thank you very much! :) And how could I pass in the input value as a parameter ? `document.getElementById('edtNoteTitle').value` for example    `<button type="button" id="btnCreateNote" onclick="NoteController.CreateNote(document.getElementById('edtNoteTitle').value)">Create</button>` ?

Comment: youre welcome, about second question - almost, it should be `onclick="NoteController.CreateNote(" + document.getElementById('‌​edtNoteTitle').value‌​ + ")"`

Comment: Thank you :) that helped